# Custom Domain on Azure Kubernetes with Ambassador API Gateway

Tags: azure, ssl, kubernetes

I am trying to configure an Ambassador Gateway on Kubernetes with Letsencrypt & cert-manager on Azure.

I am receiving the following errors in the cert-manager logs -

```
Error getting certificate 'ambassador-certs': secret "ambassador- 
certs" not found
certificates controller: Re-queuing item "default/<certificate-name>" due 
to error 
processing: http-01 self check failed for domain "<certificate-name>"
```

If I then create the secret in Kubernetes called ambassador-certs it starts to log the following -

```
Re-queuing item "default/<certificate-name>" due to error processing: 
no data for "tls.crt" in secret 'default/ambassador-certs'
```

My configuration is as follows -

Kubernetes Secret

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
 name: ambassador-certs
 namespace: default
type: Opaque
```

Kubernetes Certificate

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: <name>
spec:
  secretName: ambassador-certs
  commonName: <domain-name>
  dnsNames:
  - <domain-name>
  acme:
    config:
    - http01:
      ingressClass: nginx
    domains:
    - <domain-name>
issuerRef:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  kind: ClusterIssuer
```

Kubernetes ClusterIssuer

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    http01: {}
```

I installed Ambassador as directed from their site -

```
kubectl apply -f 
https://getambassador.io/yaml/ambassador/ambassador-rbac.yaml
```

WhenI tried this with an Ingress Controller the certificates were created and added to the secrets successfully. What am I missing with Ambassador please?

Finally, according to the Ambassador website this is all I need to do

> Certificate Manager
>
> Jetstack's cert-manager lets you easily provision and manage TLS
>   certificates on Kubernetes. No special configuration is required to use >Ambassador with cert-manager.
>
> Once cert-manager is running and you have successfully created the >issuer, you can request a certificate such as the following:

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: cloud-foo-com
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: ambassador-certs
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: cloud.foo.com
  dnsNames:
  - cloud.foo.com
  acme:
    config:
    - dns01:
        provider: clouddns
      domains:
      - cloud.foo.com
```

> Note the secretName line above. When the certificate has been stored in
>   the secret, restart Ambasador to pick up the new certificate.

Thank you. Slowly dying inside trying to resolve this :-)

## EDIT

I deleted everything and reconfigured firstly with Ambassador using http. That worked. I was able to browse to my httpbin.org route over http successfully. I then switched to port 443 on the Ambassador Service yaml and re-applied all as above.

This is still being logged in the cert-manager logs

```
Re-queuing item "default/<certificate-name>" due to error processing: no data 
for "tls.crt" in secret 'default/ambassador-certs'
```

> kubectl describe secret ambassador-certs

```
Name:         ambassador-certs
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:
Type:         Opaque

Data
====
```

Comment: can you examine `kubectl describe cert/ambassador-certs` and\or post here

Answer (score 0):

This basically means that the challenge failed .